# Regarding instrumentation test cases for APK

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application that parses RSS feed from a website.

I have developed instrumentation test cases for application since I have access to code. So far everything is ok.

Now I want to ask is there any way or is it possible through which I can develop instrument test cases for apk when I don't have access to code.

If yes then what are all components in Android that can be tested through.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to ask is there any way or is it possible through which I
>   can develop instrument test cases for apk when I don't have access to
>   code.

You can test it using **[Appium](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?ruby#native-android-automation)**

> If yes then what all components in Android can be tested through.

I have tested UI and flow for app.